# How to unit test a method that contains a 'where' or uses a 'namedquery' using Spock/Build-Test-Data?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

i tried several combination but i am not able to test a method that relies in Grails 'where'   query or 'named-query'.

Using Grails 2.0.3 by the way!

**code in service**

```
def findPersonInCity(name, city) {
    Person p = Person .where{fullname =~ name && cities.contains(city)}.find()
}
```

**test**

```
@Build([Person,City])
class PersonSpec    

    // code omitted

    def "Find a person by name"() {
        when:
        City city = City.build(name: "NY")
        Person.build(fullname: "test", city)
        Person found = personService.findPerson("test", city)

        then:
        found.name == "test"
    }    
}
```

What am i missing to succesfully unit test my 'where' query or 'named-queries' ?

The error i am getting seems to be related to a associated property.
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder.cities() is applicable for argument types:

When only quering the name it seems works.. :(

Comment: Please post an error message if you have some. Also, do you use @Mock to mock Person domain?

Comment: I extended the code sample a bit.. My guess is that is has to do with associated properties.. but i am not sure about this and i am using @Mock(Person)

Comment: You don't need to `@Mock` if you've got `@Build` there.  `@Build` takes care of mocking behind the scenes and would be redundant.     With the code you've shown above, you don't show where `cities` is defined, and without it you'll see the error that you're mentioning.  Is `cities` a hasMany that you're not showing?   Also, this isn't valid: `Person.build(fullname: "test", city)`.  Build expects a Map.  Might be worth taking build-test-data and spock out of the picture and making a simple `GrailsUnitTestCase` that instantiates a new City & Person and calls your method.